# Solving this equation for $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$ 0 = x\cos\theta\cos\phi+y\sin\theta\cos\phi+z\sin\phi$$

Here's what I've tried doing.

$$\begin{align}
  x\cos\theta\cos\phi+y\sin\theta\cos\phi & = -z\sin\phi \\
  x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta & = -z\tan\phi \\
  x\cos\theta+y\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} & = -z\tan\phi \\
  y\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} & = -x\cos\theta-z\tan\phi \\
  y^2-y^2\cos^2\theta & = x^2\cos^2\theta-z^2\tan^2\phi+2xz\cos\theta\tan\phi \\
  0 & = (x^2+y^2)\cos^2\theta+2xz\tan\phi\cos\theta-y^2-z^2\tan^2\phi
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
  \cos\theta & = \frac{-2xz\tan\phi\pm\sqrt{4x^2z^2\tan^2\phi-4(x^2+y^2)(-y^2-z^2\tan^2\phi)}}{2(x^2+y^2)} \\
  \cos\theta & = \frac{-2xz\tan\phi\pm2\sqrt{x^2z^2\tan^2\phi+y^2(x^2+y^2)-x^2z^2\tan^2\phi-y^2z^2\tan^2\phi}}{2(x^2+y^2)} \\
  \cos\theta & = \frac{-xz\tan\phi\pm y\sqrt{x^2+y^2-z^2\tan^2\phi}}{x^2+y^2} \\
\end{align}$$

However, the $\pm$ is throwing me off. I'm assuming that either the $+$ or $-$ gives a complex solution or something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: First of all $(1- \cos^2 \theta)$ is not equal to $\sin \theta$

Comment: Still not right my friend. $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$. But I think the answer below pretty much solves it. Don't think this was meant to be solved in a quadratic way. Btw are you sure there aren't anymore conditions mentioned for $x, y $ and $\phi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT :**

$$
x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=r\cos(\theta-\alpha),
$$
where $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $\tan\alpha=\dfrac{y}{x}$. You may refer to this [link](http://www.examsolutions.net/maths-revision/core-maths/trigonometry/equations/Rsin-cos-types/example-1.php).

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I reduced it to $$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-z\tan\phi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: @user137794 You are welcome...